# Gwibber 3.1.5 almost unuseable

Tags: gwibber

After a recent update my Gwibber installation is almost totally useless.  I'm wondering what the process is to totally uninstall my system of Gwibber and all its' files and start over with a completely new installation.  The version I'm having problems with is 3.1.5 and would like to downgrade to the last stable version.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add the ppa that you installed gwibber 3.1.5 - to go back to version 3 on natty you will need to `ppa-purge` the ppa.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have installed the [gwibber-daily ppa from launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~gwibber-daily/+archive/ppa) you would copy and paste the following into a terminal:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gwibber-daily/ppa
```

This will revert you back to the default v3 natty install of Gwibber.

Answer (score 1):

As fossfreedom pointed out, you need to purge the PPA. You can avoid doing that if you know how to downgrade packages using Synaptic, or if you want to reinstall gwibber.

To do the reinstall method (which will potentially remove a few other packages that you can easily reinstall), open synaptic, disable the Gwibber-daily ppa (I'm guessing you used that one), reload your sources, remove all gwibber-*, *gwibber and gwibber* packages, and install gwibber and the related packages again.

- [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Comment: Sorry but I'm more or less a total kid in Linux-land.  Any way you could provide more detailed instructions or point me to a tutorial or link?  TIA!